# Is this Java in "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" or fancy pseudocode?

Tags: java

I've started reading "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming". Seems like a great book. It claims to have examples written in Java, and it really seems this way in the beginning, to the level that they can be copied and run as-is. However, quite quickly I start to see features which I had no idea were in Java. I guess they're not and the book simply uses fancy Java-like pseudocode, but it still doesn't hurt to verify.

I'm talking about things like:

1. Using the existential quantifier in a while condition, e.g.

> while(\exists k != me) (level[k] >= i && victim[i] == me)

(replace \exists with the actual mathematical sign; recall that Haskell has similar things).

1. Using tuples and lexicographical ordering built-in to the syntax, e.g.

> (label[k], k) << (label[i], i)

Which compares the left component and if needed, the right component.

As far as I know this is pseudocode and not Java, but I'm hardly familiar with this language.

Comment: It's not Java. But don't know what that is. Looks like some kind of functional language..

Comment: Maybe it's some functional language that can be run in the JVM?

Comment: I don't know of any langauge which adds a \ syntax to methods/functions.

Comment: Peter, as I said, in the book instead of \exists there's the actual mathematical sign ($\exists$, which would be shown if we had LaTeX support here).

Comment: \exists reminds me of  http://kutruff.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/using-%E0%B2%A0_%E0%B2%A0-to-throw-exceptions/ while it's written for .Net (C#) it works in java as well.  So you can use extended characters for method names, but as far as I know not operators.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Java. I didn't check in detail, but e.g. `02~Chapter_02.zip/ch02/Mutex/src/mutex/Bakery.java` from the [book's website](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/v2/companion.jsp?ISBN=9780123705914) seems to be the program the first code fragment originate from expressed in "real" Java.